# Iphone String DateTime To int with change format

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have String include this `2012-07-16 10:20:25` and I want to change the `DateTime` Format to `yyyyMMddHHmmss` it will be `20120716102025` and want to but this number in `int` var.

I tried.

```
NSDateFormatter *ConvertFormat;
int *DateTimeConverted;

ConvertFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[ConvertFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];

DateTimeConverted = [ConvertFormat stringFromDate:StringDateTime];
```

Comment: Can I ask why your wanting an int in that format? Would you not be better storing a timestamp instead?

Comment: What is `StringDateTime`'s value ? Why don't you use the `NSDate` object ? Or its timestamp value ?

Comment: because i want to use it in core plot chart.

StringDateTime's include = "2012-07-16 10:20:25" and i want it int = 20120716102025

Answer (score 0):

It would most likely be better to find some other more accurate workaround, such as using seconds from 1970 (or whatever), but if you must do it this way....

Using `NSDateComponents` you grab each digit from the string you need:

```
NSDateComponents *todayComponents = [gregorian components:(NSWeekdayCalendarUnit |NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit) fromDate:date];
NSInteger day = [todayComponents day];
NSInteger month = [todayComponents month];
```

The above example is not complete, but should give you an idea of how it is done.

Then you would need to create a string of integers formed by all the above values, something like:

`NSString *stringDate = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i%i",day,month];`

Then convert that back into an int value:

`int finalValue = [stringDate intValue]`

I've never done this, but it would be my initial approach.

Comment: Don't forget that `int` isn't wide enough to store 20120716102025.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that storing dates in such way is silly and you should use something else (like timestamps). That being said, here comes my answer.

We may convert the string to a `NSDate` object then back to a string and get the integer value. Don't forget to use a integer type wide enough to hold the value (such as `long long`).

```
NSString *dateString = @"2012-07-16 10:20:25";
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *date = [formatter dateFromString:dateString];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMddHHmmss"];
NSString *numericString = [formatter stringFromDate:date];
long long value = [numericString longLongValue];
```

But we may also consider that the string has nothing to do with dates but is just a container for a bunch of numbers we want to concatenate. In that case, we just need to remove the unwanted characters. This is faster:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2012-07-16 10:20:25";
NSMutableString *string = [NSMutableString stringWithString:dateString];
[string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(16, 1)]; // remove last colon
[string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(13, 1)]; // remove first colon
[string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(10, 1)]; // remove space
[string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(7, 1)];  // remove last hyphen
[string deleteCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(4, 1)];  // remove first hyphen
long long value = [string longLongValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try to add to your code the following line:

```
long long int DateTimeConverted = [[ConvertFormat stringFromDate:/* your date object */] longlongInt];
```